# Envoy Proxy not working (Segmentation fault) after updating to Monterey

Tags: envoyproxy

I have a 2018 Intel Macbook that recently updated to Monterey 12.0.1. I also updated Envoy Proxy to the latest 1.20.0. But then everytime I launch the binary I got the `Segmentation Fault` error.

So I wonder if you also have experienced the same issue. And whether there is a fix for that. I searched around and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I have the exact same issue after upgrading to Monterey 12.0.1. I had installed envoy with Brew, and I get the same error after doing an uninstall and install.

Comment: Tried on a colleague's laptop and had the same issue.. I sent Enovy a crash report email a few days ago but unfortunately have not heard back yet.